# mod_rewrite .php being added to end, how change to just before first slash?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to remove .php from my urls and so I am using this htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +SymlinksIfOwnerMatch +MultiViews
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ /$1.php [L]
```

This works fine for urls like this `mydomain.com/news`

But for urls like this `mydomain.com/news/1/news_title` it's being rewritten as `mydomain.com/news/1/news_title.php` which obviously gives a 404 error.  Can anyone help me change the RewriteRule to add `.php` to just after the first forward slash instead of at the end so that the url is rewritten `mydomain.com/news.php/1/news_title`?

Many thanks for any help and advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will work for you:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +SymlinksIfOwnerMatch +MultiViews
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(.*) /$1.php$2 [L]
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply, but your coding gives a 500 Internal Server Error when I try to access any url other than the homepage.

Comment: @SammyBlackBaron: Could you give me an example of such an url, please?

Comment: `http://www.mydomain.com/section/2/1/test` - I can see that your rewriting code has done exactly what I want as `http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/` shows it's now getting rewritten as I wanted - but I don't know why there is a 500 server error now.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @SammyBlackBaron, do you use some additional RewriteRules?

Comment: Not in my htaccess file I don't, but I'm using an off-the-shelf ecommerce package that seems to be able to rewrite urls without using htaccess (in PHP?).  If I go to `http://www.mydomain.com/section.php/2/1/test` manually without anything in htaccess, the page loads fine.  It's just that I wanted to remove `.php`, hence the question. Thanks.

Comment: I've marked your answer as accepted as your code does do what I asked.  If it gives a 500 server error, that's my problem.  Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: You are welcome.
Maybe you should create a new question including some details about your package and ask why this is happening.